# preg_replace проблемы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как изменить ответ https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/87895/62977 чтобы заменить не только `links`, `images` и `css`, но и `src=\u0022https:\/\/http://sites.ru/all/themes/omega/omega/css/modules/system/system.base.css?` и `background:url("http://sites.ru/all/image.png")`?

Я пробовал https://regex101.com/r/3d5rvE/1, но получаю разные ошибки:

> 1
>   Warning: preg_replace(): No ending matching delimiter
>   2
>   Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u

Comment: Слеши экранировать не забываете?

Comment: например это `(src|href|: |:|@import )(url\(|=)(|"?)(|\\u0022?)http(s?):(\/\/?|\\\/\\\/?)sites` ка экранировать в пхп preg_replace? Ставлю по 2 слэшаб по четыре ...

Comment: по два не надо, по одному \/

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [следующее регулярное выражение](https://regex101.com/r/WSS2ZO/1):

```
(\bsrc=|\bhref=|(?:\bbackground:|@import)\s+url\()(["']|\\u[A-Za-z0-9]{4})https?:(?:\\?/){2}
```

В функции `preg_replace`:

```
$res = preg_replace('~(\bsrc=|\bhref=|(?:\bbackground:|@import)\s+url\()(["']|\\\\u[A-Za-z0-9]{4})https?:(?:\\\\?/){2}~', '$1$2', $s);
```

**Основная проблема — найти знак обратной косой черты, обратного слеша. Чтобы в строке указать этот символ, необходимо использовать 4 обратных слеша.**

***Описание***

- `(\bsrc=|\bhref=|(?:\bbackground:|@import)\s+url\()` - одно из трёх:

  - `\bsrc=|` - `src=` как целое слово или
  - `\bhref=|` - `href=` как целое слово или
  - `(?:\bbackground:|@import)\s+url` - `background:` или `@import` как целое слово, затем 1+ пробельных символов (`\s+`), а затем `url`
- `(["']|\\u[A-Za-z0-9]{4})` - `"`, или `'`, или `\`, затем `u`, а затем 4 цифры или буквы ASCII (`[A-Za-z0-9]{4}`)
- `https?:(?:\\?/){2}` - `http`, 1 или 0 символов `s`, замте `:`, а потом 2 последовательности 1 или 0 символов `\`, после которого следует `/`.

[PHP-демо](https://ideone.com/id8iTs):

```
$re = '~(\bsrc=|\bhref=|(?:\bbackground:|@import)\s+url\()(["\']|\\\\u[A-Za-z0-9]{4})https?:(?:\\\\?/){2}~';
$str = 'src=\\u0022https:\\/\\/sites/all/themes/omega/omega/css/modules/system/system.base.css?
@import url("https://sites/all/themes/omega/omega/css/modules/system/system.base.css?oe7dml");
src="http://sites/all/themes/omega/omega/css/modules/system/system.base.css?
href="https://sites/all/themes/omega/omega/css/modules/system/system.base.css?
one five six two twox
src=\\u0022https:\\/\\/http://sites.ru/all/themes/omega/omega/css/modules/system/system.base.css? и background:url("http://sites.ru/all/image.png")';
$result = preg_replace($re, '$1$2', $str);
echo $result;
```

Результат:

```
src=\u0022sites/all/themes/omega/omega/css/modules/system/system.base.css?
@import url("sites/all/themes/omega/omega/css/modules/system/system.base.css?oe7dml");
src="sites/all/themes/omega/omega/css/modules/system/system.base.css?
href="sites/all/themes/omega/omega/css/modules/system/system.base.css?
one five six two twox
src=\u0022http://sites.ru/all/themes/omega/omega/css/modules/system/system.base.css? и background:url("http://sites.ru/all/image.png")
```